# Android app fails to load on some phones in PathClassLoader

Tags: android, android-activity, classloader, classnotfoundexception, runtimeexception

I have an app, let us call it 'com.company.foo', with a main Activity 'FooBar'. In my AndroidManifest.xml, I have

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  >
    <activity android:name="FooBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
</application>
```

(where the dots contain other activities inside my app). In this form, it works fine on my HTC desire and on the emulator. However, a (very) small number of people who downloaded the app from the market report a crash with

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.company.foo/com.company.foo.FooBar}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.foo.FooBar in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.company.foo-1/pkg.apk]

Someone suggested to replace the `android:name="FooBar"` with `android:name=".FooBar"`, which again works fine on my phone and the emulator, but fails on some other devices. If I leave this attribute out altogether it will not let me install at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have an app published on Android Market. And sometimes I receive similar crash reports. Seems that's not your fault. This can be reproduced if your app is installed on SD card. Eject this card without unmounting it and run your app.

Additional information can be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/242effaaac01463a).

Comment: That thread indeed seems to be related, though nobody as of yet seems to have a better solution than 'if it fails, re-install'. After which the problem can still return at some later stage...

Comment: I'm not sure it can be fixed in app. Some crash reports are just related to Android's problems and we have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have shown is fine, can't see anything wrong with it - so what else have you looked at?

1. Have you checked the SDK level against the android release on teh phones that have failed?  Any chance of some incompatability there?
2. Instantiating the activity I have found to my cost is a non-trivial matter and there are so many things to go wrong - you will have to go back over all your support files and make sure that they are clean but think about incompatabilities.
3. You have not said what imports are involved - have you tried cutting down your app to the bare minimum and see does it still cause problems with those small number of rogue phone - maybe you dont have access to the phones?
4. Try posting the phone makes/models that are causing problems, also where to access your app and there might be someone out here with the same make/model who would be willing to do some testing for you

Sorry I can't be more help,

Good  Luck!!

Oliver

Comment: All good points, but I do not know which phone brand/model this problem appears on (I only get to see the limited information on the market dashboard). It certainly is not point 1.